# How to swipe smoothly using by gesture in android?

Tags: android, scrollview, swipe, gesture

I can swipe my images using gesture in android. But I am not able to swipe smoothly. My code is [here](http://pastie.org/8195837). My scroll is very hard to swipe. I ran my project in emulator. How can I resolve this? Can anybody help me to achieve smooth swipe?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to make a swipe like in Google Play Store/Apps. There is a Control called ViewPager. Have a look [there](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can look at [FragmentPagerAdapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) which may well be overkill for what you're doing.